# plymouth eats CPU

Tags: boot, 18.04, plymouth

I often have the situation, that my Notebook get slow.

I identify `/sbin/plymouth`  with htop.

I change /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="plymouth:debug"
```

and get following in journal

```
Okt 24 14:46:10 beelzemon plymouth[1098]: [./plymouth.c:1128]                                          main:daemon not running
Okt 24 14:46:10 beelzemon plymouth[1098]: [./plymouth.c:1139]                                          main:no need to wait
Okt 24 14:46:11 beelzemon lightdm[1128]: [./ply-boot-client.c:183]                       ply_boot_client_connect:could not connect to /org/freedesktop/plymouthd: Connection refused
Okt 24 14:46:11 beelzemon lightdm[1128]: [./plymouth.c:1128]                                          main:daemon not running
Okt 24 14:46:11 beelzemon lightdm[1128]: [./plymouth.c:1131]                                          main:ping failed
```

What is not working

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure plymouth
```

or

```
sudo plymouth --quit
[./ply-boot-client.c:183]                       ply_boot_client_connect:could not connect to /org/freedesktop/plymouthd: Connection refused
[./ply-boot-client.c:184]                       ply_boot_client_connect:trying old fallback path /ply-boot-protocol
[./ply-boot-client.c:190]                       ply_boot_client_connect:could not connect to /ply-boot-protocol: Connection refused
[./plymouth.c:1128]                                          main:daemon not running
[./ply-boot-client.c:810]        ply_boot_client_detach_from_event_loop:detaching from event loop
```

It is annoying. I cannot deinstall it, because it will also removes lightdm.

found [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1756030) without any solution or workaround.

Comment: Have you tried removing `plymouth`? See [#556372](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/556372) comment 16 if you want to have a dummy `plymouth` package to satisfy dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I will  build a dummy package with equivs.

Comment: Looks like it's not listed as a requirement on 18.04, so maybe you don't even need the dummy package.

Comment: `aptitude why plymouth
i   lightdm Depends plymouth (>= 0.8.8-0ubuntu18)`